# When two homeomorphic hypersurfaces have homeomorphic tangent cones?

Tags: ag.algebraic-geometry, at.algebraic-topology, cv.complex-variables, complex-geometry

We have the following adapted problem of the problem proposed by Zariski in 1971.

**Problem B'**. Let $f,g:(\mathbb{C}^n,0)\to (\mathbb{C},0)$ be germs of complex analytic functions. If there is a homeomorphism $\varphi:(\mathbb{C}^n,V(f),0)\to (\mathbb{C}^n,V(g),0)$, then is it true that their projectivized tangent cones are homeomorphic?

This problem was answered negatively by [Bobadilla in 2005](http://link.springer.com/article/10.1007/s00222-005-0441-4). However, I have some questions about this problem.

1) What are minimal impositions that we need to Problem B' have a positive answer?

Weaker questions are the following

2) Let $f,g:(\mathbb{C}^n,0)\to (\mathbb{C},0)$ be germs of complex analytic functions with isolated singularities such that $C(V(f),0)$ is a hyperplane. Suppose that there exists a homeomorphism $\varphi:(\mathbb{C}^n,V(f),0)\to (\mathbb{C}^n,V(g),0)$. Then

a) is it true that the projectivised tangent cones $\mathbb{P}C(V(f),0)$ and $\mathbb{P}C(V(g),0)$ have the same homotopy type? or

b) is it true that $C(V(f),0)\setminus \{0\}$ and $C(V(g),0)\setminus \{0\}$ have the same homotopy type?

P.S.: $C(V(f),0)\subset \mathbb{C}^n$ is the tangent cone of $V(f)$. In fact, writing $f=f_m+f_{m+1}+...$ as a sum of homogeneous polynoimials, we have
$$
C(V(f),0)=V(f_m).
$$